# Automatically Send Print Job to Printer on Email Trigger

Tags: mac, printer, automation, productivity

I'm looking for a way (on Mac OS) to automatically send print jobs to a printer when a certain email (sent to a fulfillment email address) is received.  Kind of like a do-it-yourself print-on-demand.

Comment: You sending the file to print also, or just a "print document #5"?

Comment: In this case, I'm doing. IF email has *keyword a* > then > print *file associated with *keyword a*

Answer (score 0):

How about using Automator that comes with any mac install and create a workflow there?

[Mac 101 Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488)